# When does the main componentWillUnmount get called for a react-native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to understand how the device OS treats my react-native app when left in the background for a longer time, I'm guessing a whole lot of smart battery-conserving-logic of the OS comes into play.

In my main index.js I'm just doing this:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './app/App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('CopilotApp', () => App);
```

..so App.js contains my main component of the entire app, which then has a StackNavigator and a bunch of stuff.

My question is - how does the lifecycle work for this main App-component? When will *componentWillUnmount* get called / will it ever?

I'm trying to keep things clean by removing event listeners and so on in there, but haven't really figured out when / if that will happen.

Answer (score -1):

On Android:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```